# ReSharper (false?) JavaScript warnings

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, resharper, intellisense

I created a default [Mail add-in for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/fp142159.aspx) project in Visual Studio 2015. It runs fine. I installed ReSharper and gives me warnings about things from Office.js and jQuery.js:

[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]

One of the ReSharper code edits ([image: hammer icon]) is to add to the top of the file [reference directives](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx) (e.g. `/// <reference path="~/Scripts/_officeintellisense.js" />`). If I add the right ones, the warnings go away. But I don't want to add code just to get ReSharper to work right. Non-ReSharper IntelliSense finds the properties/variables and the app runs fine, so I think they're false warnings.

I'm running ReSharper 9.2, Visual Studio 2015 Community.

The problem happens specifically when there's a reference directive to another .js file in the project and the Office/jQuery objects are used within a function definition (don't see the warnings on usages directly in the file, outside of function definitions).

**A simple repro case:** Create a "Class Library (Visual C#)" project, install the Microsoft.Office.js NuGet package, create JavaScript1.js and JavaScript2.js, and add the following code to the former:

```
/// <reference path="JavaScript2.js" />

function foo() {
    console.log(Office.cast.item.toItemCompose(Office.item.mailbox.item));
}
```

At this point I see warnings like those in the screen shots.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a cleaner solution to the warnings?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this in R# 9.1. Just created a new project (simple C# library) and added a `Microsoft.Office.js` package reference + created a .js file containing `console.log(Office.cast.item.toItemCompose(Office.item.mailbox.item))`. R# correctly detects the `Office` reference (same with jQuery).

Comment: I can repro what you see. It turns out that the behavior is triggered by having a reference directive and using the objects inside of functions. I added to the Question my version number and instructions for a simple repro case (following what you did).

Comment: Adding `/// <reference path="../../Scripts/_references.js"/>` to the top of my .js file got rid of some warnings. Perhaps ReSharper discovers files only via reference directives whereas IntelliSense [uses various ways](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). The ["Update JavaScript References" command](http://madskristensen.net/post/the-story-behind-_referencesjs) takes care of more (but not all) warnings, but adds 100+ references, so it's ugly. It's too bad dependency discovery isn't automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In lieu of a better answer, I'm chalking the warnings up to:

- ReSharper only discovers dependencies by crawling reference directives
- ReSharper only shows the errors inside functions. This seems like a bug.

For now, I'm working around the problem by including a reference directive to _references.js and making sure it references the libraries in question.

If anyone has a different/better answer, I'm open.